# Overriding default key binding in XMonad

Tags: xmonad

Here is a very simple XMonad config I am starting with.

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = xmonad $ def
    { modMask = mod4Mask  -- Rebind Mod to the Super key
      terminal = "alacritty"
    }
```

The only thing it does is:

1. Overrides the default modifier key.
2. Overrides the default terminal.

How can I override the keybinding for launching a terminal?
I am aware of the [additionalKeysP](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Util-EZConfig.html#v:additionalKeysP) thingy, it works, but it does not overrides the default keybindings, it just adds keybindings and I want to override the default instead of adding.

Please help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be straightforward, but you can overwrite default key like this:

```
`additionalKeysP`
  [ ("M1-C-t", spawn "") -- Default key.
  , ("M1-C-a", spawn "alacritty") -- New key for launching alacritty.
  ]
```

Function `spawn "A"` execute command `A` in a shell (e.g. `spawn "ls -a"` execute shell command `ls -a`). So you should rewrite `spawn "alacritty"` to your favorite code launching alacritty.

I don't know well about shell command for launching alacritty.

I'm assuming:

0. You are using `modMask = mod4Mask` in your xmonad.hs.
1. You know how to use `additionalKeysP`.
2. The default key is `Alt+Ctrl+t` for launching a terminal.
3. You want to launch a terminal by key `Alt+Ctrl+a`.
4. The shell command `xmodmap` output is like this (It's important `Alt` keys are contained group `mod1` at now.):

```
$ xmodmap

xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
...
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Alt_L (0xcc),  Meta_L (0xcd)
...
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
```